# pass a url variable with fetch api

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to pass an url variable through the api fetch but I can't get any results back. Thanks, I am a bit of a newbie to Javascript.

```
//Get IP address
fetch('https://extreme-ip-lookup.com/json/')
  .then((eip) => {
    return eip.json();
  }).then((eip) => {
    document.getElementById('ip').value = eip.query;
    var myip = document.getElementById('ip').value;
    var url = "https://api.pray.zone/v2/times/today.json?ip=" + myip;
  })

//Get City
fetch(url)
  .then((res) => {
    return res.json();
  }).then((res) => {
    document.getElementById('city').value = res.results.location.city;
  })
```

I can get ip address but not city.

Comment: `fetch` is a Promise, so you should be able to return the url value in the method `then`. Or move the second `fetch` right after to the url assignment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`url` is only visible inside the `.then` callback, and doesn't even exist when you make the second call to `fetch`.

Call the second `fetch` in there and return the promise that `fetch` returns so that you can chain them properly:

```
//Get IP address
fetch('https://extreme-ip-lookup.com/json/')
  .then((eip) => {
    return eip.json();
  })
  .then((eip) => {
    document.getElementById('ip').value = eip.query;
    var myip = document.getElementById('ip').value;
    return fetch("https://api.pray.zone/v2/times/today.json?ip=" + myip);
  })
  //Get City
  .then((res) => {
    return res.json();
  })
  .then((res) => {
    document.getElementById('city').value = res.results.location.city;
  })
```

Related: [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: That's great! It works perfect. You're right, it was inside the '.then' callback.

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs asynchronously and you are calling the fetch before you get the url.

```
//Get IP address
fetch('https://extreme-ip-lookup.com/json/')
  .then((eip) => {
    return eip.json();
  }).then((eip) => {
    document.getElementById('ip').value = eip.query;
    var myip = document.getElementById('ip').value;
    var url = "https://api.pray.zone/v2/times/today.json?ip=" + myip;
    fetch(url)
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      }).then((res) => {
        document.getElementById('city').value = res.results.location.city;
      })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The url variable is not in scope so practically you are passing undefined into the second fetch... You can easily put the second fetch before the closing of the first fetch or you define the url variabl outside of the first fetch and maybe assign it to an empty string then assign the url value or the url after you have built it before closing the first fetch. That's if you want to keep the fetch APIs saparated the way you have it now